# System view of an operating system

Tags: operating-system

As system view of an operating system refers to the resource allocation aspect of the OS. How can we improve the system view of an operating system.

Comment: ......by adding more detail, eg some examples of how resources like CPU, memory, disk, keyboard are managed as resources.

Comment: INB4,no.  please research it yourself.